# GCC seemingly misses simple optimization

Tags: c++, gcc, assembly, optimization

I am trying to introduce a generic function with the semantics of ternary operator: `E1 ? E2 : E3`. I see that compiler is able to eliminate calculation of one of `E2` or `E3` depending on `E1` condition for the ternary operator. However GCC misses this optimization in case of `ternary` function call (even when `E2`/`E3` have no side effects).

In the listing below function `ternary` is written to behave similarly to the ternary operator. However GCC emits potentially heavy call to function `f` which seems can be eliminated for some input values (exactly how it is done for ternary operator) because `f` is declared with pure attribute - please look at the godbolt link for assembly code generated by GCC.

Is it something that could be improved in GCC (room for optimization) or does the C++ standard explicitly prohibit such kind of optimizations?

```
// Very heavy function
int f() __attribute__ ((pure));

inline int ternary(bool cond, int n1, int n2) {
    return cond ? n1 : n2;
}

int foo1(int i) {
    return i == 0 ? f() : 0;
}

int foo2(int i) {
    return ternary(i == 0, f(), 0);
}
```

Assembly listing with `-O3 -std=c++11`:

```
foo1(int):
  test edi, edi
  jne .L2
  jmp f()
.L2:
  xor eax, eax
  ret
foo2(int):
  push rbx
  mov ebx, edi
  call f()
  test ebx, ebx
  mov edx, 0
  pop rbx
  cmovne eax, edx
  ret
```

https://godbolt.org/z/HfpNzo

Comment: It "works" with `__attribute__ ((const))`.

Comment: @melpomene: `__attribute__ ((const))` means the function can't even read globals, while `__attribute__((pure))` means it can read globals but has no side-effects.  (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#Common-Function-Attributes).  So I think it's a missed optimization to not optimize away the call, because we know it has no side-effects.  And it works in the `foo1` case, but that's because the C abstract machine doesn't evaluate `f()` in the not-used side of the ternary.

Comment: @eXX: you should probably report this as a keyword=`missed-optimization` bug on GCC's bugzilla.  https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/enter_bug.cgi?product=gcc.

Comment: *"or does the C++ standard explicitly prohibit such kind of optimizations?"* The standard allows for any optimization provided the resulting executable's behavior is equivalent to an unoptimized one. See [The as-if rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if).

Comment: Heh. If I change `foo1` to `int t = f(); return i == 0 ? t : 0;`, GCC doesn't optimize it (it always calls `f`), but then it compiles `foo2` into `jmp foo1`.

Comment: One thing that will make this tricky is that there is absolutely no indication that the function call is expensive, and there *is* an indication that *not* calling the function is expensive: that requires an extra branch.

Comment: @hvd good point, but isnt "more than one brach" are reasonable estimate for the cost of a function call?

Comment: @user463035818 Indeed, if *some* reasonable estimate has been chosen by the GCC developers, then I would expect this optimisation to be performed. But I would not have any idea how a reasonable estimate would have been chosen.

Comment: Interesting that the latest clang does not optimize it even with const attribute: https://godbolt.org/z/58Vnt6

Comment: In the call to `foo2()` the language requires that all parameters to a function are evaluated before the function is called. **EVEN** if the function is inlined the compiler is forced to evaluate all those expressions as a requirement of the language. Now the compiler can then apply the `as-if` rule after the fact and try and optimize away the call to `f()` if there are no side affects but this is not really that simple an optimization. So your comparison is apples to oranges.

Comment: What happens if you use lazy parameter evaluation using lambdas? `foo3(i, [](){return f();}, [](){return 0;});

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I see that compiler is able to eliminate calculation of one of E2 or E3 depending on E1 condition (as long as E2/E3 has no side effects) for the ternary operator.

The compiler doesn't *eliminate* it; it just never optimizes it into a `cmov` in the first place.  **The C++ abstract machine *doesn't* evaluate the not-used side of the ternary operator.**

```
int a, b;
void foo(int sel) {
    sel ? a++ : b++;
}
```

compiles like so ([Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:%27int+a,+b%3B%0Avoid+foo(int+sel)+%7B%0A++++sel+%3F+a%2B%2B+:+b%2B%2B%3B%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:57.39278337990523,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g82,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,trim:%271%27),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-O3%27,source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+8.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B%27,t:%270%27)),k:42.60721662009477,l:%274%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)):

```
foo(int):
    test    edi, edi
    je      .L2                # if(sel==0) goto
    add     DWORD PTR a[rip], 1   # ++a
    ret
.L2:
    add     DWORD PTR b[rip], 1   # ++b
    ret
```

The ternary operator can only optimize to an asm `cmov` if neither input has any side-effects.  Otherwise they're not exactly equivalent.

---

**In the C++ abstract machine (i.e. the input to gcc's optimizer), your `foo2` does always call `f()`, while your `foo1` doesn't.**  It's no surprise that foo1 compiles the way it does.

**For foo2 to compile that way, it would have to optimize away the call to `f()`.**  It's always called to create an arg for `ternary()`.

---

There is a missed-optimization here, which you should report on GCC's bugzilla (use the `missed-optimization` keyword as a tag).  https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/enter_bug.cgi?product=gcc

**A call to  `__attribute__ ((pure)) int f();` *should* be able to be optimized away<sup>1</sup>.  It can *read* globals, but must not have any side effects that affect anything else in the program.**  (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html)

As @melpomene discovered in comments, `__attribute__ ((const)) int f();` does give you the optimization you're looking for.  An `__attribute__((const))` function can't even read globals, only its args.  (Thus with no args, it must always return a constant.)

HVD points out that gcc doesn't have any cost info for `f()`.  Even if it *could* have optimized away the call to `((pure)) f()` as well as to `((const)) f`, maybe it didn't because it didn't know it was more expensive than a conditional branch?  Possibly compiling with profile-guided optimization would convince gcc to do something?

But given that it made the call to `((const)) f` conditional in `foo2`, gcc may just not know that it can optimize away calls to `((pure))` functions?  Maybe it can only CSE them (if no globals have been written), but not optimize away entirely from a basic block?  Or maybe the current optimizer just fails to take advantage.  Like I said, looks like a missed-opt bug.

---

**Footnote 1**: GCC and clang will optimize away `pure` function calls entirely, not just collapse repeated calls down to one.

```
//__attribute__((const))  // truly pure function of its args, can't even read globals

__attribute__((pure))  // no side effects that the rest of the program cares about.
int foo(int);

int bar(int a) {
    foo(a);
    return a;
}
```

[**Godbolt**](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGe1wAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxCAAnKQADqgKhE4MHt6%2BekkpjgJBIeEsUTHxdpgOaUIETMQEGT5%2BXLaY9nkM1bUEBWGR0XoKNXUNWc2DXT1FJRIAlLaoXsTI7BwA%2BqtMBATEeBFeBJjrUAmLmDMzJhoAggD0N%2Bub27v7h6tQaAyD5wDU33ff2y8tAAnt8TsRMN8qF4GJUBJcrsECFDUKgIEiLgBmKzXBFI74RWrowTfJgzb4mADsOKuv1%2B/DRZJM2IRdO%2BEIIiwYpOZNKpABEERw5rROABWXh%2BDhaUioThuazWb4KBZLSHmTE8UgETTCuYAaxAmMkADoxWKNLFzVwAGxim2xMwaMz6TiSSW62WcXgKEAabW6uZwWAwRAoVAsBJ0aLkShoSPRmLAAAcLqwADc8MsAGp4TAAdwA8glGJwtTRaAdiL6IBFPRFgrVgWXeA3mMRgYWItoKjruLx42xBIWGCDPVg9sA3GJaL7%2B6QsCxDMBxNLePgIZV05g5zLMKoKi8W%2BRBK1PbRdsQmx4sJ6niwW3MqAZgApcwXi6X5/xBCIxOwpBkQRFBUdQ11IXRmgMIwUEVSx9F2X1IDmVAEnaOcAFpC0xb4MIAdRnXDBnQZl%2BWABgvDgiwuEpXhUG3YgdiwJCIDmco4T8CBXBGJoXUCYJemKfpMUSZJUgEHiJBdHJxIYSY%2BhiET2PaTphk8RopJaNoqiGboBKmYTbF0ySuBdcY6nkoTFLY1VllmV0OAlUgpRlOUOG%2BVRkxtDCbUkb5gGQZBvmTE0zG%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%2B7yluQYXgs2zbwsinbQe38HuoNEAzDFBGypASRTWNDQbWdMxkwVTMNVF0%2BNWa%2BmJoGDm3MQADSGvzCM41ohTTYJwWaABJIQbgMLZnZOmNKAVvjn2XKtSkV8tSYG2iQPA6A9pR0OgBWOshTpgRlEnS611boM3um1J6L19hvQ%2Bp5U%2BfliFGEvhoa%2BgNEGJlBpieKbNSZQxhv0eGDNSpI0qnaWImJYiNSypIVG6NWos29LYTqJNkqpXWpiWxdj7H2PppwJmJij6E0UclBmZhD6PXcZYuYDEUjOEkEAA%3D%3D%3D) - GCC and clang both compile to just the `mov eax, edi` to return the first arg.  They even warn about the function call being useless since the return value isn't used:

```
# GCC
<source>:6:8: warning: statement has no effect [-Wunused-value]
     foo(a);
     ~~~^~~

# clang
<source>:6:5: warning: ignoring return value of function declared with pure attribute [-Wunused-value]
    foo(a);
    ^~~ ~
```

Comment: One observation is that if `i == 0` is true and the value of `f()` is used, then it must be the value that would have resulted if `f()` had been called at the point where the abstract machine would have called it.  In this case there's no difference, but if any globals or escaped locals had been written in between, they could affect the value returned by `f()` (since a `pure` function can read them).  That is, the compiler can't reorder a call to a `pure` function past a write to any global.  As such, it might be reluctant to try to reorder `pure` calls very much at all.

Comment: Also, it seems to me that the natural way for the compiler to discover this optimization would be to try to sink the unconditional call to `f()` past the branch, effectively transforming the expression into `i == 0 ? f() : (f(), 0)`.  Then it could notice that, since `f` is pure, the `(f(), 0)` can be replaced by `0`.  But the first step (sinking) is itself somewhat unnatural, since in most cases you would expect such a transformation to result in worse code.  So maybe it's not attempted.